# Ubuntu 18.04: Error resolving "hotspot_name": Name or service not known

Tags: networking, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.  Yesterday I had no trouble with WiFi connection.
Today, I connect to the same hotspot but I am not able to connect:

> Error resolving 'hotspot_name': Name or service not known

Here is how I set the content of the relevant files:

**/etc/hostname**

```
begueradj
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
17.0.0.1 localhost
17.0.1.1 begueradj
```

I did not have **/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg** but I created it and set:    `preserve_hostname: true`

I run: `sudo service network-manager restart`

I am still getting the same problem

Any suggestions?